# Mac Mini mid 2011 - any way to keep the analog audio input out of power saving mode?

Tags: audio, mac-mini

This machine (mid-2011 with 10.16 retrofit) is used as a HTPC/media player in a somewhat interference-rich environment.

As long as there is some kind of media playback active, even if it is video with a silent audio track, all is fine. However, a few seconds after no longer playing back anything, it appears the sound circuitry powers down leaving the output in a somewhat high-impedance state, leading to all kinds of noise being picked up by the analog wiring (ticking noises that appear to be from some SMPS in the system if not using an audio isolation transformer, hum injected into the same transformer if using one). Is there some hidden software option to simply keep the sound circuitry on line (actively outputting silence) at all times?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps out of left field, untested & not free [though free trial to test]…

I wonder if something like a dither will keep the audio alive sufficiently to do this.
You could test [SoundSource](https://www.rogueamoeba.com/soundsource/) with an AU dither plugin, maybe this from Airwindows - https://www.airwindows.com/tpdf-dither/ which seems to have a freeware license.

I'm not quite sure how you'd set it in practise; perhaps set your Mac's audio out to 24-bit & set the dither to 16-bit, That would mean it's always doing 'something' to the bottom 8-bits [unless it's smart enough to stop processing when its not getting signal.]

I can't test any of this theory, as I don't suffer from the symptom. I use a hardware S/PDIF > analog 5.1 converter on my HTPC Mac, for other reasons. If no joy, that could be another alternative to try out. You can get these generic converters for about $£€ 25 on eBay/Amazon. They're 'good enough'.

You could also try ferrite beads [a few quid/bucks/shekels on eBay] - placed toward the signal input end - but I'm less convinced this is the panacea people would have you believe. It should work to some extent on high-frequencies, but not so much broad-spectrum.